# What is the difference between ILU(0) and ILU(1)?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I know that ILU (0) has the same sparsity pattern as that of the original matrix A, and while performing the Gaussian elimination all the fillins are ignored. But I am not clear how ILU(1) or ILU(2) and so on work. What is the difference between ILU(0) and ILU(1), and how the sparsity pattern is chosen in ILU(1)?

Comment: Is Saad's discussion of $ILU(p)$, see http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/PS/iter3.pdf, useful?

Comment: @P.Siehr: Thanks for such a nice reply and thanks for telling me that I should accept the answer. I never knew this before. Moreover, I cannot upvote as I don't have 15 reputations :(

Comment: You are welcome. Have a look at the [tour page](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). (You can also find it in the menu of the help-button, located at the top right.)  All basics are explained on that page. Another page you will find useful is the [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the best way to explain the ILU decomposition is with pictures. Let $A$ be the band matrix from the 5-point-star of the Finite Difference method
\begin{align*}
A&=\begin{pmatrix}
B_m & -I_m & \\
-I_m & B_m & -I_m \\
 & -I_m & B_m & -I_m \\
 &  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
 &&& -I_m & B_m & -I_m  \\
& &&& -I_m & B_m  \\
\end{pmatrix}∈ℝ^{n×n}, \\
B_m&=\begin{pmatrix}
4 & -1 & \\
-1 & 4 & -1 \\
 & -1 & 4 & -1 \\
 &  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
 &&& -1 & 4 & -1  \\
& &&& -1 & 4  \\
\end{pmatrix}∈ℝ^{m×m}.
\end{align*}

The structure of that matrix looks like this (for $m=5$):
[image: A]

The $LU$-Decomposition given by $A=LU$, has the typical fill-in
[image: L][image: R]

The ILU($0$) factorisation takes the sparsity pattern of $A$. Hence, if $A_{ij}=0$, the entries $L_{ij}$ and $U_{ij}$ are set to $0$.

The ILU($0$) matrices look like:

[image: L_ILU_0] [image: R_ILU_0]

With these two matrices the ILU($0$) factorisations reads: 
$$A\approx A_0 = L_0U_0.$$
And the sparsity pattern of the matrix $A_0$ is

[image]

You can see some additional entries, compared to the sparsity pattern of $A$. These exist simply, because we set the fill-in of the original $LU$-Decomposition to $0$.

The ILU($1$) factorisation now takes the sparsity pattern of the ILU($0$) matrix $A_0$. Therefore if $[A_0]_{ij}=0$, the entries $L_{ij}$ and $U_{ij}$ are set to $0$.

[image: L_1] [image: R_1]

With these two matrices the ILU($1$) factorisations reads: 
$$A\approx A_1 = L_1U_1.$$

And the ILU($2$) decomposition would again take the sparsity pattern of $A_1$.

---

I recommend Yousef Saad's book *Iterative Methods for Sparse Linear Systems*. It is the best book for that kind of stuff.